# Elasticsearch python получение одного поля документа

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

Допустим есть документ со следующими полями:

```
id
title
text
date
```

мне нужно вернуть список id.
на данный момент делаю так:

```
es = Elasticsearch([host, ],
                   http_auth=(user, passwd),
                   port=9200
                   )
s = Search(using=es, index='docs', doc_type='doc')
s.source(['id', ])
es_ids = [h.meta.id for h in s.scan()]
```

Но мне кажется что это как то не оно. Получается ко мне приходят все документы (или я не правильно понимаю?) а их там на данный момент более 100к и скоро будет в сотни раз больше. 
Подскажите как возвращать только одно поле. списком, может есть такое?
Может быть надо использовать какой нибудь **Q** из **elasticsearch_dsl** ?
Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно делал все правильно но надо добавить параметр

```
s = s.params(size=8000)
```

На сколько я понял это размер ответа. Получается достаточно быстрою. И при увеличении количества шардов этот параметр будет умножаться на количество шардов.